# How to continue thick underline beyond text?

Tags: soul

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\setul{}{2pt}
\ul{\Huge\textbf{Some text}}
\underline{\Huge\textbf{Some text \hspace{1in}}}
\ul{\Huge\textbf{Some text \hspace{1in}}} % This line causes error
\end{document}
```

The command `\underline{\Huge\textbf{Some text \hspace{1in}}}` produces the result

[image]

I want the underline to be thicker though, so I tried using the soul package, setting the thickness, and then `\ul{Some text}`

This gives me the desired underline thickness

[image]

The problem occurs when I try to combine the two to get a thick line extending beyond the text. The command `\ul{\Huge\textbf{Some text \hspace{1in}}}` produces an error, "Missing number, treated as zero."

Any ideas why or how to fix it? Or better ways of underlining text with a bold line that extends an arbitrary distance beyond the text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try `\protect\hspace*{1in}`

Comment: Doing `\ul{\Huge\textbf{Some text \protect\hspace{1in}}}` fixes the error but cuts the underline off at the end of the text... produces same result as second image above

Comment: `\ul{\Huge\textbf{\mbox{Some text \hspace{1in}}}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm jealous.  You knew the answer, I had to look it up in the package manual. :(

Comment: @R.Schumacher: I had some suspicion, but I was unsure. And just wanted to answer, when your answer appeared. You were quicker  ;-) (+1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to read the fine print in the soul manual http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/soul/soul.pdf  You have to protect with \mbox{}.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
\ul{\Huge\textbf{Some text\mbox{\hspace{1in}}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, that worked for me, thanks. I read that doc but didn't realize that line of the table applied.

Answer (score 6):

Without loading any other packages, here's a command that will accomplish this using a rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newlength\ae@tmp@length
\newcommand\aeunderline[2][]{%%
  \settowidth\ae@tmp@length{#2}%%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{#2}%%
  \hspace{-\ae@tmp@length}%%
  \rule[\dimexpr-0.25ex-4pt]{\dimexpr\ae@tmp@length+#1+0pt\relax}{4pt}}

\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  \aeunderline[2in]{Hello World} and this is what follows.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### plain TeX based

A solution with underline based on plain TeX means only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \leavevmode
  \vtop{
    \Huge
    \hbox{\textbf{Some text \hspace{1in}}}
    \kern.5ex % space between text and line
    \hrule height 2.5pt % rule thickness
  }
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### TikZ based

The following example uses TikZ, which offers more options regarding the line style. For example, this version shows round line caps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  {\Huge
  \tikz[
    baseline=(text.base),
    node font=\bfseries,
    inner sep=0pt,
    line width=2.5pt,
    line cap=round, % also decorations, ...
  ]
  \draw
    node (text) {Some text}
    (text.south east) ++(1in, -.5ex) coordinate (tmp)
    -- (text.south west |- tmp)
  ;}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result TikZ]

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness of the answers to this question, if you are using luatex, there is an unfinished package that underlines: [luauline](https://github.com/grizzilus/luauline/). (It is usable, it just isn't ready enough for CTAN since it has no documentation and needs a few performance improvements.)

If you download this package and place it in your local TeX tree, you can load it and produce the desired result with the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{luauline}
\setluaunderlineheight{2pt}  % set thickness of the underline
\begin{document}
\uline{\Huge\textbf{Some text\hspace*{1in}}}
\end{document}
```